# VSCode Workspace Markdown Preview Disappear

Tags: visual-studio-code

Edit: I realized this might be some strange bugs with VSCode that nobody has seen before so I open an issue there instead.

I'm having a strange issue as stated, the built in Markdown support for VSCode has disappeared from my VSCode Workspace. All the other workspace are unaffected, just this single workspace that is doing the strange thing.

What I did:

- Disabled certain extensions in Workspace only (nothing to the Global)
- Create Workspace specific extensions.json
- Use the `Disable All Installed Extensions for this Workspace` command
- Use the `Show Recommended Extensions` command
- Enabled recommended extensions in Workspace only (nothing to the Global)
- Tried to do `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V` to bring up Markdown Preview
- Nothing happened and Markdown Preview disappear from Keybindings
- Tried reproducing the error by duplicating the folder and open a new Workspace
- Unable to reproduce error, neither reload nor restart help fixing the error

Bad Keybindings

[image: Bad Keybindings]

Good Keybindings

[image: Good Keybindings]

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 3):

Got it fixed, apparently the built in extension `vscode.markdown-language-features` was disabled and build in extensions wasn't shown in the installed extensions list.

To find it, gotta search for `@builtin markdown` for it to shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because I met the same problem.

In my case, I installed other extension about markdown that turn off my preview button, and I finally don't need to type open preview every single time when I trying to open my MD. (lol